# Bash script is not working on many files by using for loop

Tags: bash, sed

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOL_atom_index=116101
number=1
SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
index=1
for index in {1..100}
do
    for SOL_index in {116101..136845}
    do
            sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_8_new_$index.ndx
            SOL_atom_index=$(($SOL_atom_index+3))
        number=$(($number+1))
        SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
    done
done
```

I have many text files which names are: eq2_8_new_1.ndx, eq2_8_new_2.ndx, ......   eq2_8_new_100.ndx

I try to use my script on all files. I use variable "index" and for loop, so I expect that this part of code will work on every file

```
for SOL_index in {116101..136845}
    do
            sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_8_new_$index.ndx
            SOL_atom_index=$(($SOL_atom_index+3))
        number=$(($number+1))
        SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
    done
```

Did you see this? Here I have a sed command which will work on specific file (at the end of the line I have eq2_8_new_$index.ndx

```
            sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_8_new_$index.ndx
```

So if I use for loop (for index in {1..100}) I expect that this will work on every text file from eq2_8_new_1.ndx to eq2_8_new_100.ndx
BUT my script change only the first file (eq2_8_new_1.ndx and the is no changes in otherfiles).

Comment: Are you sure that your script finishes ? Can you start with a simpler example ? Create some directory with sample of files and try to do less `sed` commands per file. + 1 advice : don't use `-i` option here. You will be lost if some files are parsed and others not. Write output on an other directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ls` with wildcard eg:

```
for eqfile in `ls -l /*.ndx`
   do
     sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" $eqfile 
   done
```

Comment: you can simply do : `for eqfile in *.ndx`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working. I have only numbers and they dont change to SOL, I dont know why