# Rewrite for loop with sed to awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a huge problem. Could you help me

My script change number in text file (SOL_atom_index for example 117824) to text with number (SOL_mol_index, for example SOL125). I try to rewrite number of **atom** to number of water **molecule**. Water molecule consist of 3 atoms and in this text file all water atoms have index from 116101 to 136845.
So 116101 atom + 116102 atom +116103 atom = first water moelcule (SOL1).etc. so for example 116101 will change to SOL1, 116102 will change to SOL2, 116103 will change to SOL1, 116104 will change to SOL2, 116105 will change to SOL2 ,116106 will change to SOL2, 116107 will change to SOL3, etc:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOL_atom_index=116101
number=1
SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
index=1
for index in {1..100}
do
    for SOL_mol_index in {116101..132777}
    do
        sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_12_333_new_$index.ndx
        SOL_atom_index=$(($SOL_atom_index+3))
        number=$(($number+1))
        SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
    done
    SOL_atom_index=116101
    number=1
    SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
done
```

Is it possible to rewrite this to something like for loop in awk to awk?

```
    for SOL_index in {116101..136845}
    do
            sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_12_333_new_$index.ndx
            SOL_atom_index=$(($SOL_atom_index+3))
        number=$(($number+1))
        SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
    done
```

I ask, because I try to use sed and run this script in many files (thats why have for index i {1..100}), but It doesnt work [Bash script is not working on many files by using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680155/bash-script-is-not-working-on-many-files-by-using-for-loop). So I will try do this for loop in awk and then save the file and the use bash for loop to make change in all files

My input

```
151 117760
275 117841
533 124168
920 126658
1054 124285
1819 123172
2073 119893
2086 119350
2210 121552
2215 126925
2726 126379
3113 120949
```

Expected output for example:

```
151 SOL554
275 SOL581
533 SOL2690
920 SOL3520
1054 SOL2729
1819 SOL2358
2073 SOL1265
2086 SOL1084
2210 SOL1818
2215 SOL3609
2726 SOL3427
3113 SOL1617
```

Another input example to test (because this script works on many files):

```
13 119740
1054 122809
1694 118417
2086 121990
2602 120586
2731 123091
3242 119419
3629 117304
3750 124873
```

```
7370 116332
7499 116464
7624 120970
7749 126085
7757 116644
8011 126892
8140 122509
```

For example this script works perfect on one file

```
#!/bin/bash
SOL_atom_index=116101
number=1
SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
for SOL_index in {116101..136845}
do
        sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_8_new_100.ndx
        SOL_atom_index=$(($SOL_atom_index+3))
    number=$(($number+1))
    SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
done
```

but when I try to modify this script to working on one houndred files it doesnt work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain why 117760 becomes SOL554 and 117841 becomes SOL581 ? Please explain the rule behind your code

Comment: I try to rewrite number of atom to number of water molecule. Water molecule consist of 3 atoms and in this text file all water atoms have index from 116101 to 136845.
So 116101 atom + 116102 atom +116103 atom = first water moelcule (SOL1) etc.

Comment: @Jakub: What do you mean by "does not work"? One problem with your script is that you are creating about 1.7 million child processes of `sed`, and simply replacing them by `awk` won't make this better. Also, in the rewriting attempt you posted, I don't see any awk call.

Comment: I try to do this and I have still the same number they not change for example 116101 is not change to SOL1

Comment: @Jakub : Another problem in your original script is that the inner `for` loop has `SOL_mol_index ` as controlling variable, but inside the loop body, you modify this variable: `SOL_mol_index=SOL$number`. This won't work, as you can see with the following example: `for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; i=89; done`.

Comment: You provide an _example input_ and _example output_ in your question, but I don't see where this data is passed to your script or a result would be written.You just modify files with the naming pattern `eq2_12_333_new_$index.ndx` and each of such modifications is done 16676 times. I would replace the inner loop by a program, which just loops over the lines of the respective `eq2_....` file, doing the necessary replacements for each line, in a single process.

Comment: How's the speed? Are the files small? This seems like it would be horribly slow on anything of size...

Answer (score 1):

Yes I found answer, I dont know what was wrong, but finally

```
#!/bin/bash
SOL_atom_index=116101
number=1
SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
index=1

for index in {1..100}
do
    for SOL_index in {116101..136845}
    do
            sed -i "s/$SOL_atom_index/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+1))/$SOL_mol_index/g;s/$(($SOL_atom_index+2))/$SOL_mol_index/g" eq2_12_333_new_$index.ndx
            SOL_atom_index=$(($SOL_atom_index+3))
        number=$(($number+1))
        SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
    done
    SOL_atom_index=116101
    number=1
    SOL_mol_index=SOL$number
done
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).